# Mapping election data by zip

Tags: data, united-states, zip-codes

I am trying to create a map of Presidential election results by ZIP code, but all I have been able to find is election data by county (too broad) and precinct (too narrow).

Does anyone know of a public data set that maps election data to ZIP code?

Comment: [opendata.se] is the location to look for open data. You should always specify the country which is the subject of your search. I would suspect any US election data by zipcode to be inaccurate, since there is a many-to-many relationship between zipcodes and precincts.

Comment: Like New York Times? https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/upshot/2020-election-map.html (Mapbox vector tiles are behind this)